# WordPress core code contains things marked as deprecated by... Wordpress?

Tags: wpdb, deprecation

I have some problems matching this message in my WordPress network update page:

> You have the latest version of WordPress. Future security updates will be applied automatically. If you need to re-install **version 4.9.4**, you can do so here:

With the one I just noticed after temporarily enabling debug mode:

> Notice: wpdb::escape is deprecated since **version 3.6.0**! Use wpdb::prepare() or esc_sql() instead. in /home/user/public_html/blog.network/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3846
>
> Notice: get_current_site_name is deprecated since **version 3.9.0**! Use get_current_site() instead. in /home/user/public_html/blog.network/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3846

What am I missing? How can core WordPress code still use code that its very own developers marked as deprecated? How can I update *functions.php* file in *wp-includes* to not use deprecated code and methods?

Comment: One of your plugins or your theme is causing this, not WordPress.

Comment: For a longer explanation, read Pat J‘s answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 3846 in `wp-includes/functions.php` is in a function named [`_deprecated_function()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_deprecated_function/), which warns about the use of deprecated functions. I did a quick search of my copy of 4.9.4 core and didn't find any instances of `wpdb->escape()` or `get_current_site_name()`, the two functions you're *actually* being warned about.

Most likely, the deprecated functions are in a plugin or a theme. If you disable all plugins and switch to a default theme (such as Twenty Seventeen), the **Notice**s should go away.

Comment: You are -- of course -- correct. The sad thing here is that _faulty_ plugin is "WordPress MU Domain Mapping". It is no longer updated, because [it is no longer needed](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/). However, I must keep using it, because [cited counter-solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/) requires: (a) a clean install and (b) a dedicated IP address. Both things not possible in my case.

Comment: I'd say you've got two paths to choose from: a) [fork the plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15379/how-to-fork-a-plugin) and replace the deprecated function calls with the recommended replacements, or b) make the conscious choice to ignore the **Notices** thrown by the plugin.

Comment: Can I  (at all or how?) mute notices thrown by only this single plugin? Or is it either all notices (muted) or none?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I had hopes for the `deprecated_function_trigger_error` filter, but it appears to globally turn deprecation notices on or off, instead of allowing you to pick and choose the notices to suppress.