# How to revive (or take over) a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I have been using a neat plugin to make sites multilingual. The last update to the plugin was 5 years ago - and it is broken as of WP 5.5.

I have signed up to the WordPress plugins site, but can find no way to sign up to (or even contact!) a project. Nor can I find a contact for a site moderator or suchlike.

How do you do that? How can one take over leadership of an abandoned project?

Answer (score 0):

See the two answers for "How to Fork a Plugin" at [How to fork a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15379/how-to-fork-a-plugin) .

I like both of the answers. Contacting the author for a response. If no response, copy then modify/improve/rename, crediting the original author in the code and readme. You should give it a new name.

Comment: Thank you for that link. Honestly though, I would rather join their team than fork it -- that would also help the many thousands (as reported by WP) of existing installations. But I understand, if nobody on the original team responds, there is no formal reassignment process?

Comment: Also, given only their WP account name -- HOW do I contact the original author? I could find no contact form / personal messaging feature / email address for any of the team members...

Comment: I'd look inside all of the code files (available via the WP repository), or via the plugin page (on WP).

Comment: Ok so it's expected that there's no PM system or such. Good to know.